# Rewrite rule for changing url from filetype to category

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have the following urls:

```
http:/testdomain.com/file_type.html
http://testdomain.com/file_name.html
```

I want to be able to change them to:

```
http://testdomain.com/file-type/
http://testdomain.com/file_name/
```

But any url that comes in which has the format of something_something.html
I want to change to /something-something/

I a just upgraded my site to wordpress so all the old urls that i have for seo i want them to still work

I tried the following rewrite condition but of course it didn't work

```
rewriterule ^file_name.html(.*)$ http://testdomain.com/file-name/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

And i know if it did work it would be specific to that file only, but i was just trying to test

Comment: Just search on [so] about converting `_` to `-` using `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: i just tried searching for "converting _ to - using mod_rewrite" and results return 0

Comment: Any help would be very much appreciated